# Please help me understand how these vectors work

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, notation, vector-fields

Say I have a vector $R$ in general relativity where $$R = sin(\theta)\partial_{\theta} + cos(\theta)cos(\phi)\partial_{\phi} $$

What does the index of $R_{i}$ mean? I'm currently thinking of this as the $i^{th}$ index of an $R$ vector but I don't know what that vector would be in this case. Does a $\partial_{\theta}$ correspond to a (1,0) vector here?

Any explanation would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're talking about a vector field on the $2$-sphere, expressed in the standard angular coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$. For all points $p$ where these coordinates are well-defined, the set of tangent vectors $\{\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi\}$ constitute a basis for the tangent space $T_p\mathrm S^2$, which means that an arbitrary vector $\mathbf R$ can be expanded
$$\mathbf R = R^\theta \partial_\theta + R^\phi \partial_\phi$$
where $R^\theta$ and $R^\phi$ are the coordinates of $\mathbf R$ in the basis $\{\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi\}$.

In general, it is convenient to index the coordinates with integers $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$, in which case the local basis is provided by $\{\partial_{x^1},\ldots,\partial_{x^n}\} \equiv \{\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n\}$ and an arbitrary vector can be written
$$\mathbf R = R^1 \partial_1 + \ldots +R^n \partial_n \equiv R^\mu \partial_\mu$$

Comment: So in this case, $R^{i = \phi} = cos(\theta)cos(\phi)$?

Comment: @mathPhys Yes, that’s right.